Why Lord Vishnu appeared in two Avatars of Narasingha and Varah , when only one could have killed the brother-duo of Hirankashyap & Hiranaksha?
The arrogant HIRANKASHYAP was killed by the Narasingha avatar of Lord Vishnu to protect his devotee Prahlad. During the same time period Hirankashyap's elder brother HIRANAKSHA  was killed by a Varah , who itself is considered an incarnation of Lord Vishnu. Why the almighty God could not take care of two enemies of humanity in his single Avatar?

God doesnt even need to take avatar to kill someone just by mere taught he can get out of the living being which he was part of including hiranaksha and hiranyakashipu.. its only for bhakta who do bhakti need hi lila so that he can think and remember gods past time in saving.. and also deep spirtual meeaning of aaksha (setting eyes and gold or keeping gold or wealth hidden out of greedyness excessive wealth) varaha destroyed is this taught in the humans ..

@PrasannaR Do you mean to say most of what is extoled in puranas are mere fictions?

It's by to His own sweet will. Lord Vishnu doesn't need to take even one avatar to kill the demons. By His mere sankalpa, they will be vanquished. Paritranaya Sadhunam... It's for the supreme spiritual pleasure of His pure devotees so they get a chance to glorify God through various prayers and thus remember Him. Killing of the asuras is secondary.

@Jagbir Singh Kanet what i told the story can be used for your benefit there is no question of fiction in the stories this are events happened in different manvantra different yuga, some of which happened outside earth plane, varaha and narasimha..i Have answered your question why god needs to take avatara, it is for the benefit of devotees.. not only parahlad in case of narasimha avatra we can learn many things from prahlad he suggest how to do perform nava vidha bhakti (9 aspects of devotion)

asking 'why' is asking for opinions. please read forum rules

They had boons to be not killed by man beast deva bird etc.so Lord took form of Half lion half man etc to circumvent the boons and kill them
